# Webpack combine html-loader with file-loader to copy templates

Tags: webpack, webpack-html-loader

What I'm trying to do is combine `html-loader` to copy assets referenced from html templates e.g. `<img src="some/path/here.jpg" />` and `file-loader` to copy those html templates into the bundle folder. **I do not want** to embed those html files directly in the javascript bundle.

I thought this will work but it ain't:

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    loaders: ['file-loader?name=templates/[name]-[hash].[ext]', 'html-loader']
},
{
    test: /\.jpg$/,
    loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
}
```

I end up having this in my copied html template:

`module.exports = "<img src=\"" + require("../img/image.jpg") + "\" />";`

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

to clarify.

the my html template has the following content:

```
<img src="../img/image.jpg" />
```

After running webpack the `image.jpg` is **not** copied to `assets/` folder. The html template **is** copied to the `templates/` folder but its content is:

```
module.exports = "<img src=\"" + require("../img/image.jpg") + "\" />";
```

whereas I'd like it to be:

```
<img src="../assets/image-webpackHashHere.jpg" />
```

and of course the image should be copied there under the computed name (with hash).

Comment: Not work how? Images not processed by webpack?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify the scenario.

Comment: Use https://github.com/peerigon/extract-loader#extracting-the-indexhtml